# Best way to store large amount of files in Java EE 6 Application (Database/Filesystem)

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, persistence

I'm developing an application that needs to deal with several document files (PDFs, DOCs, etc.).

I'm using PostgresSQL 9.2 to store these files as large objects and Hibernate Blob to write and read them as stream in a way to not overload the memory.

My question is if there is a best way to deal with it? Or store a large ammount of binary files in database is a good approach? Maybe store the files in the filesystem is faster, but that not guarantee the integrity of the data neither the scalability.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your need and use cases. At least there is nothing wrong to store them as blobs in the db. If you already have your database and store other relevant data with it and also need them in an consistent way, then your approach may be the only good one.

Of course, if you have some requirements which the database cannot fulfill or when you think it's overkill to use a db because you have no requirements which a database normally fulfills, then you may think of other approaches.

Storing in the filesystem has some disadvantages as you mentioned. But if you have some restrictions, like the same name is not used twice, and only one instance is writing the same file, no need for transaction/rollback etc. the filesystem approach wins on the aspect of simplicity.

For example if you need to scale, because you store so much data that one machine is not enough to store them, you may want to consider NOSQL technologies to scale the storage.

Your question is so open, that I could write forever of several options.

Comment: Does storing files as blob will lead to OutofMemoryError ?? I was dealing with a number of files in my application and storing files as encoded strings in android sqllite database and which leads to OutofMemoryError when total file size reaches 20 mb, which may include hundreds of files.Does using blob leads to the same problem??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of data you are trying to store sometimes hibernate isn't really that useful, to me this sounds to me like it may be one of the cases. Pulling a flat file into a Java object probably isn't going to buy you that much in the end. You may want to think about storing your files in a  document-oriented database like MongoDB instead. What you are doing is just what these type of databases were made for.